# Map output with multiple "Zoom Levels" in QGIS 3

Tags: qgis-3, print-composer, scale

Just wondered if it is possible to do BBC-style multiple "Zoom Levels" output in QGIS 3 like this:

[image: a example from BBC News]

I used to use another app such as Adobe Illustrator to overlay the maps of different scales. However, as the maps were independent, it was neither fast (another step in another App) or precise (centres' coordinates may differ).

In the report I am working on, I intend to analyse a number of cases around the world, each of which is accompanied by a group of maps like the above example.

How can I have one underlying map for each location and export, say, three maps of different scales?

Comment: Hi, from what I understand its just 3 map frames with different scales? and some lines / boxes.

Comment: Adding overviews in the print composer will handle highlighting the precise extent of the larger scale map frames.

Comment: you can start with this tutorial for example, which produces a map with one overview: http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/3/making_a_map.html

Comment: Thank you all! Yes, the "Center on overview" option under Overviews in Print Layout is what I was looking for.